# ActionMailer not sending email though rails logs indicate it has been sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to implement actionmailer to send out task reminders via email when the show action in the tasks controller runs. When running on local host, my log indicates that the mail is sent, but it doesn't arrive at the destination.

My development.rb:

```
Emailtest::Application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'my_app.com',
    user_name:            ENV['xxx@gmail.com'],
    password:             ENV['xxx'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # required for heroku
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

end
```

My user_mail.rb

```
class UserMail < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "bri.lobdell@gmail.com"

  def task_reminder(task)
    @task = task
    @url = 'http://example.com/login'

    mail(to: @task.recipientemail, subject: "You've been sent a reminded")
  end

end
```

The line from the show view that calls the mail to be delivered

```
<% UserMail.task_reminder(@task).deliver%>
```

**UPDATE**

My task index:

```
<tbody>
      <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
        <% if current_user.id == task.user_id%>
          <tr>
            <td><%= task.title %></td>
            <td><%= task.description %></td>
            <td><%= task.recipientname %></td>
            <td><%= task.recipientemail %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <td> <%= render 'tasks/send_mail' %></td>

          </tr>
        <%end%>

      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

My form: _send_mail.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/tasks/send_mail", method: "post", url: send_mail_path) do  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, 'task.id' %>
<%= submit_tag "Remind" %>
<% end %>
```

Tasks#send_mail

```
def send_mail
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    UserMail.task_reminder(@task).deliver
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: a) Please move ```UserMail.task_reminder(@task).deliver``` to the controller. Don't put it on the view. b) When you're testing, is @task.recipientemail the same as the 'from' email address? If that's the case, try a different email address.

Comment: where in my controller should I add it? and how do I then call it from the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call that line of code in your controller, you can make a form which will point to an action in a controller, and that action will have something like this:

```
def send_mail
@task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
UserMail.task_reminder(@task).deliver
redirect_to :back
end
```

You'd also need to enter in your routes file that controller, like so:

```
post "tasks/send_mail", :to => "tasks#send_mail", :as => "send_mail"
```

This would be your form (very simple), which would just have a button there. You could just trigger that form on page load:

```
<%= form_tag("/tasks/send_mail", method: "post", url: send_mail_path) do  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, "#{@task.id}" %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Try adding this to the top of your `send_mail` method:

```
if(params.has_key?(:task_id)
redirect_to "/"
end
```

If it redirects you, then the params are being passed, if not, we have a problem ;)

Comment: I was receiving an error when trying trying to load the page with the form. I had to change "#{@task.id}" to 'task.id' because it is being called in a loop where "@task.all" is defined as task. Now, I am getting an error regarding this line in the send_mail action in the task controller "@task" = Task.find(params[:task_id]). Couldn't find Task with id=task.id. Any ideas? * Note the "" around the "@"task lines are just so stackoverflow doesn't think im sending it to a user

Comment: Try inspecting the element (or view source) of that hidden field. What does the `value` element equal?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure how to inspect the element.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, but I caught your drift. Just inspect the element on the page. <input id="task_id" name="task_id" type="hidden" value="task.id">

Comment: Ah, so the task id is not being past through in the params hash. Can you show me what your form is looking like on your end, including the loop?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the code in the original question. What indicated that the task id is not being passed through the paramms hash?

Comment: OK, I've got it now. Where it says `<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, 'task.id' %>`, you should change it to `<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, '#{task.id}' %>`. Tell me how that goes.

Comment: When I submit the form it still takes me to an error in my TasksController#send_mail I've added that in to the main question above as well.

Comment: Oh and to answer your question, it said that literally `task.id` was being past through, when it should have been a variable past through, which would have actually outputted an ID. See my last comment for how to fix this.

Comment: Alright, it should be `@task = Task.find(params[:task_id])` Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Ahh, the error is now saying Couldn't find Task with id=#{task.id}. Any ideas? thank you for being so patient. I've attached a link to my git hub repo: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/emailtest

Comment: Try changing it to `<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, "#{task.id}" %>` (Added double quotes)

Comment: with the double quotes change I get an error saying "NameError in Tasks#index" pointing to that line.

Comment: But can you see if that task ID is being passed through in the params hash?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to test this?

Comment: Edited in a code block above. Just add it in before anything else in your `send_mail` method.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I guess that means the params are not being passed in.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting? Can you jsut copy/paste the headline?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#send_mail
Couldn't find Task with id=#{task.id}  This occurs when I click the remind button in the _send_mail.html.erb form partial

Comment: Can you please push the latest version of your code to the Github repo? I'm just gonna clone it and have a look around/

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. The repo is linked here and above: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/emailtest

Comment: Hi, I've been playing around with the code, and I found that when I set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` to `true` instead of `false`, it now raises an error when I try and send an email. This is it: `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in TasksController#send_mail` and it says "Aunthentication Required". 

What SMTP server are you going to use?

Comment: I would like to use the gmail SMTP

Comment: I made the changes you suggested in my my config files, but I'm still getting the TasksController#send_mail error indicating that it couldn't find Task with id=#[task.id}

Comment: Ahh, right, I did make a few modifications in my local copy of the code. I'll make a pull request on github when I get home, so you can merge your changes in. Would that be OK?

Comment: Would you mind giving me and upvote and accepting the answer?